# How to print a window on one page?

Tags: wpf, printing, reduce

I want to print a window on one page,but the window exceeds the printable area,
so i use pageScalingFactor to reduce its scale just like below.
But I found some printer which reduce/enlarge function be disabled does not work.
I mean it can not ajust the scale print area for me.How can i resolve this problem?

```
var printDialogTest = new PrintDialog();
PrintTicket pt = printDialogTest.PrintTicket;
pt.PageScalingFactor = 60
```

Comment: You could convert the window to a bitmap, then scale the bitmap.